# Nexus 5 on recovery mode but power button isn't working

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, recovery-mode, nexus-5

I have a Nexus 5 phone with a bad power button (completely not working). The phone was off for a while, and when I powered it on (using fastboot) it asked for cyanogenmod update - downloaded and restarted.

When the update finished the phone booted into the root screen saying "Root access possibly lost. Fix?" with "Yes", "No" options. However, since the power button isn't working - I can't select anything... 
(I can, however, go into rainbow mode! Weird, but cool)

Is there a way to simulate a button press from adb or something? Is there another way of getting over this screen?

Comment: I. Must. See. Rainbow. Mode.

Comment: It really is something you can't afford to miss

Comment: Oh god, im gonna google it now.

Comment: It is beautiful.  How is this a problem?? Hahahaha. In seriousness though,  can you get it into fastboot or adb? If so, then PC commands to the rescue.

Comment: I ended up waiting for the battery to run out. Then rebooted it using USB & fastboot. It's up and running now. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Np kiddo. Can you say all this as an answer and mark it? Dead threads get on my nerves hahahah